# Error trying to cast LazySeq to IFn

Tags: clojure

Just starting to learn Clojure with 100 doors problem. Im getting a cast error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

Here is my code:

```
(defn doors [n]
  (loop [n n 
         acc (repeat n false)]
    (if (= n 0)
      (open-doors acc)
      (do 
        (let 
          [yy (map-every-nth not acc n)]
          (recur (dec n) (acc yy)))))))


(defn map-every-nth [f coll n]
  (map-indexed #(if (zero? (mod (inc %1) n)) (f %2) %2) coll))

(defn open-doors [d]
  (for [doors d 
        n (iterate inc 0)
        :when d]
    n))

(doors 100)
```

Comment: Plz feel free to add comments about the solution.

Comment: in `doors` you're calling acc as if it were a function. That's not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that Clojure will try to execute every list that it encounters:

```
(+ 1 2)
```

Here symbol `+` is bound to function, thus the form `(+ 1 2)` is executed successfully. Even quote doesn't cancel the rule:

```
'(+ 1 2) => (quote (+ 1 2))
```

Quote form gets executed and returns its contents as result. So first element of every list in Clojure must be something executable: symbol bound to macro or function, or special operator.

In your example we see:

```
(acc yy)
```

`acc` is a lazy sequence, result of `(repeat n false)`. It cannot be executed, thus you get an error.

*Note, that there is a recursive call in your function, so arguments of `recur` are arguments of a function. In Clojure arguments of a function get evaluated before using. Arguments of a macro do not.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
(defn map-every-nth [f n coll]
  (map-indexed
    #(if (zero? (mod (inc %) n))
      (f %2)
      %2)
    coll))

(defn doors []
  (let [n 100]
    (loop [p 1
           state (repeat n false)]
      (if (>= p 100)
        state
        (recur
          (inc p)
          (map-every-nth not p state))))))
```